# How can I force recompile Cycles after modifying its source?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to modify Cycles, but I can't find a way to simply recompile it.

I've already modified the source files found in `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\addons\cycles\source\kernel` but this has no effect in Blender as the kernel is already compiled on this machine.

Is there a way I can force Blender to recompile Cycles after I've modified the source?

Comment: I guess you need to [compile and build Blender](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender) or at least the [Cycles module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/GPU_Binaries). In the folder that you mentioned, there are only *.h files. These are header files for C/CPP and only define the interface for methods. If you want to modify Cycles you need development tools, the [source code from the git repository](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/) and you need to build it. I have no idea where Cycles is.Eevee seems to be in rB/source/blender/draw/engines

Comment: Cycles has its own homepage: https://www.cycles-renderer.org/development/ , and source code is in [rB/intern/cycles](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/)